# How to get input of text controller as a double? - flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a textcontroller and need to pass the text controller value to a parameter of a class that only accepts double as the input but by default the type of textcontroller is string.

Text Controller:

```
 TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();
 ...
 child: TextField(
              controller: priceController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              autofocus: true,
            ),
```

Passing in the value go priceController to the parameters that accepts only double value:

```
LevelEventCreate(price: priceController.text);
```

However the parameters does not accept the value of priceController.text as it is a string. Any way to change it to a double value instead?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I finally figured the answer.

So I just parse it as a `double` into the parameters of the class instead.

```
LevelEventCreate(price: double.parse(targetPriceController.text)),
```