# How to get the data of TextFormField as a double in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, double

I tried double.parse to get the data of TextFormField as a double:

```
double _pointsUsing = double.parse(pointsEdditingController.text);
```

but it causes error saying "The method '>=' was called on null".
If I tried this:

```
double _pointsUsing = double.tryParse(pointsEdditingController.text);
```

it returns null.

The textformfield text value is: 1,133.00

It also says "Tried calling: <(1133.0) 1,133.00"

Comment: Can you share the code that is running the `double _pointsUsing = ...` please? I'm curious to know where in the lifecycle it is happening, and if there are listeners on `pointsEdditingController` that are running that code. Also, can you show how you are implementing `pointsEdditingController` ?

Comment: Maybe I should remove the comma programmatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790689/how-to-get-input-of-text-controller-as-a-double-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove "," from the string then after parse to double.

```
double _pointsUsing = double.parse(pointsEdditingController.text.replaceAll(",",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way :

```
print( double.tryParse('2,456.90'.replaceAll(",","")));
```